# Is wearing eye blinds every night to sleep deleterious for the skin?

Tags: dermatology, sleep

I wonder whether wearing an eye blind every night to sleep can be deleterious for the skin. I looked for information on Google and Google Scholar but haven't found anything, so I'm not sure whether it means nobody looked at it or it is obviously harmless.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this questions would have to be: *it depends.* Certainly it could irritate skin for some people with very sensitive skin, or if they use blinds made of poor quality material or which contain something they're sensitive or allergic to, or if they absorb and retain sweat in hot weather. But otherwise, blinds are usually just a piece of cloth. It would be no different than wearing any other piece of clothing to bed that fit closely to your skin such as socks or pajamas for infants and small children. Granted, facial skin is often more sensitive than most other areas of the body, but infant skin is usually even more sensitive and infants have been sleeping in fitted pajamas for decades without ill effect.

I can find nothing indicating that eye blinds are known to be deleterious to the skin and can't think of any reason why they would be other than the possibilities I mentioned above.